# Remover os primeiros commits do repo Git

Tags: git, github, commit

Existe alguma forma de reduzir o historico do git removendo os commits mais antigos?
Supondo que um repo tem 5000 commits e remover os 2500 primeiros commits.

Comment: Existe a opção de _squash_ que permite transformar vários commits em apenas um, mas [acho que] precisa de um cuidado especial para commits de merge. Qual a intenção de diminuir a quantidade de commits?

Comment: Vou migrar para o github mas quero manter o historico e lá só permite 2gb

Comment: Nesse caso, apagar commits normalmente não vai fazer grande diferença. As próprias rotinas de housekeeping que o git faz automaticamente de vez em quando conseguirá fazer uma grande compactação. O mais indicado aqui seria procurar quais são os objetos no repositório que estão pesando mais e removê-los; e a maioria desses objetos que pesam bastante são blobs, não objetos de commit nem de tree. Já tentou examinar o seu repositório atrás de saber onde está sendo de fato consumido esse espaço?

Comment: Onde eu trabalho, o repositório principal da empresa tem mais de 51k commits. Qual o espaço ocupado pelo repositório? Cerca de uns 150MB. Foi feito uma tratativa alguns anos atrás que removeu do histórico uns 5k commits, porém por motivos alheios foi necessário manter uma cópia de backup do estado anterior do repositório. Ele está praticamente parado no tempo, recebendo apenas manutenção. Ele tem 33k commits e 122MB. Notou como mesmo com 60% do total de commits do novo repositório ele tem praticamente 80% do espaço ocupado?

Comment: Esse material da Atlassian pode ajudar melhor: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/reduce-repository-size/

Comment: 2Gb por repositório? Só de código ou tem arquivos binários nesse repositório?

Comment: Qual é o tamanho da pasta .git?